# Object does not exists at location when trying to upload an image file from URI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an app using firebase storage service 
I have a function that saves an image from device local storage, uses the URI of the picture to save it to firebase -

```
private void uploadFile() {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileRefrence = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            fileRefrence.putFile(mImageUri).
                    addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, DELAY_MILLIS);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

The problem is that always when trying to click the upload button I get a toast message saying "Object does not exist at location" - does that mean that the URI is actuall false? I am confused.

edit -

here is where I create mImageUri -

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `mImageUri` is almost certainly incorrect here.  You should edit the question to show how you're creating it, and also be certain there is actually a file present at the location it points to.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited and added the point where I get the URI, which is when coming back from the ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent. Hopefully you can figure out what went wrong.